# “Graphics is not a Graphics primitive or directive.”?

Tags: graphics, warning-messages

I looked through the forum but none of what I've found is helping.

```
f[x_] := Sin[x]; 

Manipulate[  
  circle = 
    {RGBColor[1, 0.27, 0.5], {Circle[{x, f[x]}, y]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {-5, 5}}};  
  curve = 
    {ParametricPlot[{z, Sin[z]}, {z, 0, 2 Pi}]};  
  box = {RGBColor[0.81, 0.79, 1], Rectangle[{40, 0}, {50, 10}]};  
  Graphics[{box, circle, curve}, PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 20}}],  
  {x, 0, 50}, 
  {y, 0.5, 5}]
```

I'm getting the error message:

> Graphics is not a Graphics primitive or directive.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want the circle to move along the curve, so your code should be written like this:

```
f[x_] := 2 Sin[x/2]
Manipulate[
  circle =
    With[{u = x, v = f[x]}, 
      {RGBColor[1, 0.27, 0.5], PointSize[Medium], Point[{u, v}], Circle[{u, v}, r]}];
  Graphics[{box, circle, curve}, PlotRange -> {{-5.5, 50}, {-5.5, 20}}],
  {circle, None},
  {curve, None},
  {box, None},
  {x, 1, 50 - 5.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{r, 3}, 1, 5, .5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  Initialization :> (
    curve = (ParametricPlot[{z, f[z]}, {z, -5.5, 50}][[1]]);
    box = {RGBColor[0.81, 0.79, 1], Rectangle[{40, 0}, {50, 10}]})]
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 9):

The **reason** you are getting this error is that you are including the result of a plotting function inside a `Graphics` expression.  Since plotting functions produce `Graphics` objects themselves you cannot nest them inside other `Graphics` expressions.  You need to use [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) to combine them.

Wrong way:

```
plot = Plot[x, {x, -2, 2}];
Graphics[{plot, Circle[]}]
```

Right way:

```
plot = Plot[x, {x, -2, 2}];
Show[ Graphics@Circle[], plot]
```