# Show the translated version of a plot alongside another graphics object

Tags: plotting, graphics, geometric-transform

I want to demonstrate the fact that the main part of a Mandelbrot fractal is consisted of a cardioid and some circles. So at first, I wrote this line:

```
With[{cardiod = PolarPlot[(1 - Cos[t])/2, {t, -Pi, Pi},
  Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]]}, 
 Show[{MandelbrotSetPlot[], cardiod}]]
```

which results in

[image: mandelbrot]

But if I [`Translate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate.html) the cardioid to right, it won't be recognized as a `Graphics` object. For example

```
Show[{MandelbrotSetPlot[], Translate[cardiod, {1/4, 0}]}]
```

results in an error saying `Could not combine the graphics objects`. I also looked at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/191736/37848) and other linked ones and tried something like this:

```
p = PolarPlot[(1 - Cos[t])/2, {t, -Pi, Pi},
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]];
g = Graphics[Translate[p, {1/4, 0}][[1]]];
Show[{MandelbrotSetPlot[], g}]
```

but again, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Show[{
  MandelbrotSetPlot[], 
  Graphics @ Translate[cardiod[[1]], {1/4, 0}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain why we should do this?

Comment: `cardiod[[1]] ` to get the  graphics primitives and `Graphics` to convert the translated primitives (a line through many points with color and thickness specifications) back to a `Graphics` object. It should become clear when you look up `Translate` in the documentation and inspect the output of  `cardiois[[1]]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose an {x,y} parametrization and "ParametricPlot", then you can simply add some vector for a translation:

```
cardiod = 
 ParametricPlot[{1/4 + 0.5 (1 - Cos[ph]) Cos[ph],  0.5 (1 - Cos[ph]) Sin[ph]}, {ph, 0, 2 Pi}, 
Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]]; 

Show[{MandelbrotSetPlot[], cardiod}]
```

[image]